# VueTwo Way Data Binding with Nested Components

Tags: vue.js

Suppose I want to display a List of Questions.  For each question, there is a list of answers, none of which are right or wrong.  For each question, the user can choose an answer.  I'm wondering how to create two-way binding on the selected answer.

The Vue:

```
new Vue(
{
    el: "#app",

    data:
    {
        questions: [{}]
    }
}
```

Example Question Model:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Which color is your favorite?",
    selectedAnswerId: null,
    selectedAnswerName: null,
    answers:
    [
        {id: 1, name: red, photoUrl: ".../red", selected: false},
        {id: 2, name: green, photoUrl: ".../green", selected: false},
        {id: 3, name: blue, photoUrl: ".../blue", selected: false},
    ]
}
```

Components:

```
var myAnswer =
{
    props: ["id", "name", "url", "selected"],
    template:
    `
        <div class="answer" v-bind:class="{selected: selected}">
            <img class="answer-photo" v-bind:src="url">
            <div class="answer-name">{{name}}</div>
        </div>
    `
};

Vue.component("my-question",
{
    props: ["id", "name", "answers"],
    components:
    {
        "my-answer": myAnswer
    },
    template:
    `
        <div class ="question">
            <div class="question-name">{{name}}</div>
            <div class="question-answers">
                <my-answer v-for="answer in answers" v-bind:id="answer.id" v-bind:name="answer.name" v-bind:url="answer.photoUrl" v-bind:selected="answer.selected"></my-answer>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
});
```

When the user selects an answer to a question by clicking on the div, I want the Question model's selectedAnswerId/selectedAnswerName along with the answers selected property to be set accordingly.  Therefore, what do I need to add to my components in order to accomplish this two-way binding?  I believe it requires input elements and v-model, but I couldn't quite figure it out.  Also, I am only one day into Vue.js and have no experience with related frameworks.  So if I am doing anything blatantly wrong or against best practice, that would be good to know as well.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well to have two way binding, you should have some input that has v-model directive on It which is bounded to some data.So far I can't see any input here...do you want maybe use `select` input for the selecting answer ?

Comment: I want the user to click on an answer div that contains both a name and a picture.  So if the user wants to select red as their favorite color, they would click on the red picture with a title of "red".  Therefore I believe I would need a hidden input element where the answer div is wrapped in a label that triggers the correct input.

Comment: You do not need an input at all. You just need your component to accept a value and emit the input event. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events

Answer (score 0):

The answer will handle a click event and emit a (custom) selected-answer event. The question will have its own data item to store the selected answer ID; the answer component's `selected` prop will be based on that. The question will handle the selected-answer event by setting its `selectedId`.

```js
var myAnswer = {
  props: ["id", "name", "url", "selected"],
  template: `
        <div class="answer" v-bind:class="{selected: selected}"
         @click="setSelection()"
        >
            <img class="answer-photo" :src="url">
            <div class="answer-name">{{name}}</div>
        </div>
    `,
  methods: {
    setSelection() {
      this.$emit('selected-answer', this.id);
    }
  }
};

Vue.component("my-question", {
  props: ["id", "name", "answers"],
  data() {
    return {
      selectedId: null
    };
  },
  components: {
    "my-answer": myAnswer
  },
  template: `
        <div class ="question">
            <div class="question-name">{{name}}</div>
            <div class="question-answers">
                <my-answer v-for="answer in answers"
                :id="answer.id" :name="answer.name" :url="answer.photoUrl"
                :selected="answer.id === selectedId" @selected-answer="selectAnswer"></my-answer>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
  methods: {
    selectAnswer(answerId) {
      this.selectedId = answerId;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    questions: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Which color is your favorite?",
      answers: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'red',
          photoUrl: ".../red"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'green',
          photoUrl: ".../green"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'blue',
          photoUrl: ".../blue"
        },
      ]
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
.answer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-question v-for="q in questions" :name="q.name" :answers="q.answers"></my-question>
</div>
```