# Two-Way Binding in Component Scope

Tags: vue.js

Suppose I'm trying to make a simple questionnaire, where the user answers a list of questions.

```
new Vue(
{
    el: "#app",
    data:
    {
        questions:
        [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "What is your favorite color?",
                selectedId: 2,
                choices:
                [
                    { id: 1, name: "red" },
                    { id: 2, name: "green" },
                    { id: 3, name: "blue" },
                ]
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
});
```

How do I go about making a question component with two-way binding.  That is, if the user swaps their favorite color from green to red, by clicking on the respective input, the selectedId will automatically update.  I'm not very clear on how v-model works within a component.  Does it only have access to the components data?  Also, I don't understand the difference between props/data.

Comment: Isn't this the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43079230/vuetwo-way-data-binding-with-nested-components ?

Comment: The domain is, but I didn't like that I proposed my own component to begin with, because the answers provided were based on it.  I'm wondering if there is a better structure for the component itself.  Also, the other answers have left me more confused.  The docs say to use v-model for two-way binding on input.  But replies were suggesting events.  If I were to use events, couldn't I simply use JQuery or such?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you can approach this, here's my attempt:

```js
let id = 0;

Vue.component('question', {
  template: '#question',
  props: ['question'],
  data() {
    return {
      radioGroup: `question-${id++}`,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(choice) {
      this.question.selectedId = choice.id;
    },
    
    isChoiceSelected(choice) {
      return this.question.selectedId === choice.id;
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    questions: [
      {
        title: 'What is your favorite color?',
        selectedId: null,
        choices: [
          { id: 1, text: 'Red' },
          { id: 2, text: 'Green' },
          { id: 3, text: 'Blue' },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: 'What is your favorite food?',
        selectedId: null,
        choices: [
          { id: 1, text: 'Beans' },
          { id: 2, text: 'Pizza' },
          { id: 3, text: 'Something else' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

```css
.question {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/yyx990803/vue/master/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <question v-for="question of questions" :question="question"></question>
</div>

<template id="question">
  <div class="question">
    <div>{{ question.title }}</div>
    <div v-for="choice of question.choices">
      <input type="radio" :name="radioGroup" :checked="isChoiceSelected(choice)" @change="onChange(choice)"> {{ choice.text }}
    </div>
    <div>selectedId: {{ question.selectedId }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```